# What are the things to note in order to maximize the auc_roc_score?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, roc, auc

What are the **tips & tricks** to improve our `auc_roc_score`?

*Example*:

1. Is balanced data required?
2. Is recall is more important than precision?
3. Is oversampling is usually better than undersampling?

Thanks again!

Comment: This is highly dependent upon the type of data in use and the type of model it is trained on along with the hyper parameters being currently used.

Comment: assume it is a binary classification and the normal neural network with bunch of Dense layers. Just want to get the general idea (theory) in order to get a good score of auc_roc_score

Comment: I suggest you move this question to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) because it is not about programming aspects of your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly dependent upon the type of data in use and the type of model it is trained on along with the hyper parameters being currently used. The ROC is just the outcome of how well the data pre processing and model building is done. Thus you must look into ways of improving your model. Also precision and recall are useful in their own ways. It depends on the scenario.

Like `precision` answers the question :

```
What proportions of the predicted True labels were actually correct ?
```

whereas `recall` answers :

```
What proportion of the actually correct labels were identified correctly ?
```

Thus you would want a higher recall in case of identifying a corona patient while you would prefer a higher precision when it comes to the fact that the cost of acting is high and the cost of not acting is low.

Also, what exactly do u mean by balanced data varies from situation to situation.
Thus if you could specify the kind of model, problem and data in use, we may be able to help you more.

Please share the code of your model for the same.